# Error: Cannot assign value of type '[ViewController.organizations]' to type '[(sectionTitle: String, rowTitles: [String])]'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to implement a search bar into a tableview, but get the error, 'Cannot assign value of type '[ViewController.organizations]' to type '[(sectionTitle: String, rowTitles: [String])]' on the line "searchArray = dataArray.filter({$0.sectionTitle.lowercased().contains(searchBar.text!.lowercased())})". Can someone help me fix this? The ultimate goal is to use the search bar to narrow results of the list. Here is my code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    struct data {
        var sectionTitle = String()
        var rowTitles = [String]()
    }

    var dataArray = [data(sectionTitle: "section 1", rowTitles: ["row 1", "row 2", "row 3"]),
    data(sectionTitle: "section 2", rowTitles: ["row 1"]),
    data(sectionTitle: "section 3", rowTitles: ["row 1", "row 3"])
    ]
    var searchArray = [(sectionTitle: String, rowTitles: [String])]()
    var searching = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searching {
            return searchArray[section].rowTitles.count
        } else {
            return dataArray[section].rowTitles.count
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell")
        if searching {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = self.searchArray[indexPath.section].rowTitles[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = self.dataArray[indexPath.section].rowTitles[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell!
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.dataArray.count
    }
}


extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchArray = dataArray.filter({$0.sectionTitle.lowercased().contains(searchBar.text!.lowercased())})
        searching = true
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your search array type to `data` instead of `[(sectionTitle: String, rowTitles: [String])]()`

```
var searchArray = [Data]()

struct Data {
        var sectionTitle = String()
        var rowTitles = [String]()
    }
```

As per @kamran Suggestion

Comment: Also, names of types(`class`, `struct`, `enum`) and protocols are `UpperCamelCase`. Everything else is `lowerCamelCase` in `Swift`.